# How can I use ajax result as a variable that I can print everywhere in a page

Tags: php, ajax

Here is my ajax code:

```
$("#to").change(function(){
  $.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/sales/getPrice",             
  dataType: "html",       
  data: {'from' : $('#from').val() , to: $('#to').val()},    
  success: function(response){                
  //$(".location").html(response); 
 }
});             
});
```

I want to use ajax result instead of 40. (below code attached).

```
e: {
 price   : 40,
 category: 'Economy'
}
```

Comment: the `e:...` stuff is what your `getPrice` call returns? What is that? it's not json, which means you'll have to parse that text yourself. But once you've parsed it, then you can extract the price value directly from the parsed results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var result = '';

$("#to").change(function(){
  $.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/sales/getPrice",             
  dataType: "html",       
  data: {'from' : $('#from').val() , to: $('#to').val()},    
  success: function(response){                
      result = response;
 }
}); 
});
```

Now use that result where you want:

```
e: {
     price   : result,
     category: 'Economy'
  }
```

Comment: This will only work if the **async** success function is called before initializing `e`.

Comment: How can get result using php $_POST['result'];

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the data the ajax call returned? So you can use it in the `success` part:

```
$("#to").change(function(){
  $.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/sales/getPrice",             
  dataType: "html",       
  data: {'from' : $('#from').val() , to: $('#to').val()},    
  success: function(response){                
     alert(respone.price);
     console.log(response);
 }
});             
});
```

Use `console.log(response);` in the success function, to get the data in the developer console of your browser.